# Expanding and collapsing in WPF

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I want to create control like one in PDF file.In PDF,in left side pane we can see tabs like bookmark,signature etc., as image and we can expand it and collpase it.I want exactly like tht.

As im new to WPF,i referred some samples and i created tabcontrol.
Till now i achieved tabcontrols with image as Tab header.

But i don know how to add that collapse button in tabitems.And also each tab page should contains lot of iamge buttons and textbox.I do not know how to do that.
And also i dont know whether they use tabcontrol at all.
So please help me.My main thing is i want to collapse and expand entrie thing except the tab headers.

But i dont knwo how to do that in WPF.
Pls help me..And provide some samples for that.
Thank u in advance

Answer (score 1):

There is a built in control called the Expander.

You could do:

```
  <Expander>
    <Expander.Header>
      <!-- Some buttons for the header go here -->
    </Expander.Header>
    <!-- Content goes here. Maybe create a TabControl with a hidden tab header -->
  </Expander>
```

Comment: Yes,but how can i use that to collapse whole Tab items.